# Google App Engine File Processing

Tags: python, file, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a process that will upload a file to GAE to interpret it's contents (most are PDFs, so we would use something like PDF Miner), and then store it in Google Cloud Storage.

To my understanding, the problem is that file uploads are limited to both 60 seconds for it to execute, as well as a size limit of I think 10MB.  Does anyone have any ideas of how to address this issue?

Comment: The 60 seconds doesn't kick in until the file is uploaded and the handler called.  The 60 seconds is the limit you have to process the file with a front end request.  The other answer is still a better strategy, as it will scale.  Small pdf's might be ok with a front end request, but that 60 sec deadline is always there.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet could upload to blobstore or Cloud Storage, then use Task Queue to process the file which has no time limits.

Comment: Am I able to take the entire file out of CloudStorage and process it in the task queue?

Comment: you can read the file in your task, that's what you want, not "take out".

Comment: Right, forgive my mistake in words.  How would you propose GAE to be able to reference the file that was uploaded?

Comment: read the doc here, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/

Comment: I have extensively read the docs, I am asking a question not about developer advice but rather an architectural one.

Comment: when your enduser start upload a file, you will have some record for the file stored in database, then after the upload, you could start the task to process the file which has information in your database.